# HERE Maps (JS v3) - Add event listener to info bubble

Tags: javascript, here-api

I'm trying to add a pointerenter event to a [information bubble](https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/v3/maps/topics_api_nlp/h-ui-infobubble.html) but it's not firing. I got it to work with a marker but not with a info bubble.

I've tried to add the eventhandler to the info bubble using [addEventHandler](https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/v3/maps/topics_api_nlp/h-ui-infobubble.html#h-ui-infobubble__addeventlistener) like this:

```
var infoBubble = new H.ui.InfoBubble({lat:48.8567, lng:2.3508}, {
    content: "<div>hello</div>"  
});
infoBubble.addEventListener('pointerenter', function (evt) {
    alert('pointerenter');    
});
```

I've also tried adding the mouseOver event to the info bubble content element and that does not fire either.

```
var infoBubble = new H.ui.InfoBubble({lat:48.8567, lng:2.3508}, {
    content: "<div>hello</div>"  
});

mapUI.addBubble(infoBubble);

var infoBubbleContent = infoBubble.getContentElement();
infoBubbleContent.addEventListener('mouseOver', function(evt){
    alert('mouse over');
});
```

Here's the full code.

```
// Initialize the platform object:
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
'app_id': 'xxx',
'app_code': 'xxx'
});

// Obtain the default map types from the platform object
var maptypes = platform.createDefaultLayers();

// Instantiate (and display) a map object:
var map = new H.Map(
document.getElementById('mapContainer'),
maptypes.normal.map,
{
  zoom: 4,
  center: {lat:50, lng:5}
});

// Enable the event system on the map instance:
var mapEvents = new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map); 

// Behavior implements default interactions for pan/zoom (also on mobile touch environments)
var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(mapEvents);

// create default UI with layers provided by the platform
var mapUI = new H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, maptypes);

var infoBubble = new H.ui.InfoBubble({lat:48.8567, lng:2.3508}, {
    content: "<div>hello</div>"  
});
infoBubble.addEventListener('pointerenter', function (evt) {
                alert('pointerenter');
});

mapUI.addBubble(infoBubble);

/*
var infoBubbleContent = infoBubble.getContentElement();
infoBubbleContent.addEventListener('mouseOver', function(evt){
    alert('mouse over');
});
*/

var standardMarker = new H.map.Marker(new H.geo.Point(40.4, -3.6833));
standardMarker.addEventListener('pointerenter', function (evt) {
                alert('pointerenter');
});

map.addObject(standardMarker);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the InfoBubble is an event target, the only event it dispatches itself is 'statechange'. However, after adding the bubble you can get the bubble's HTML element and use plain old HTML events on it:

```
var bubble = new H.ui.InfoBubble({lat:48.8567, lng:2.3508}, {
  content: "<div>hello</div>"  
});
ui.addBubble(bubble);
bubble.getElement().addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
  console.log('hello there');
});
```

Note: The HTML for the bubble is only built AFTER it is added to the UI. Before the getElement() method return null.